# let and var Invalid redeclaration of const in Swift REPL

Tags: swift, variables, constants, read-eval-print-loop

In Swift REPL I can assign a constant with `let`, but why can I modify it later using `var`?

```
let name = "al"

var name = "bob"
```

Swift is not complaining here, but wasn't name a constant?

Comment: Is there anything else? Because those 2 lines alone do *not* compile for me (*"error: invalid redeclaration of 'name'"*)

Comment: I am on the Mac Terminal app... just type swift and have a look

Comment: `error: repl.swift:3:5: error: invalid redeclaration of 'name'`...

Comment: It does indeed produce no error my Swift 3.1 REPL, but it does not compile in Xcode.

Comment: I got an error as well 'error: repl.swift:3:5: error: invalid redeclaration of 'name'
var name = "bob"
    ^
repl.swift:1:5: note: 'name' previously declared here
let name = "al"'

Comment: Compare https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=20: "Redefining Everything with the Swift REPL"

Comment: REPL is not a good environment to check redeclaration feature. Imagine how it evaluates each line. Your code causes error in usual apps, Playground, [IBM Swift sandbox](https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl). You should not take the behavior of REPL or debugger as language feature.

Comment: Sure but it looks a bit strange anyway... Swift should be the same anywhere...

Comment: @l'L'l: That is strange. I get no error in the REPL, and according to the above-mentioned blog entry it *is* possible to redeclare a variable in the REPL.

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO: Did you try the "interactive" REPL?

Comment: @MartinR: Yes, I did `$ swift` from Terminal.app, then pasted the example from the OP directly in and received the error. Here's my env: `Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.53 clang-802.0.42)`, `Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9`, `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb "--repl=-enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -color-diagnostics"`

Comment: @l'L'l: Now it become funny: It works if you paste the lines *separately.*

Comment: @MartinR: You're right! I'm wondering why it would behave in that manner?

Comment: @l'L'l: I *assume* that the REPL compiles each chunk from stdin separately, so it makes a difference if it reads both statements in a single chunk or not.

Comment: _Swift should be the same anywhere_ No, it's not possible. With Swift's scope model, you can reference some sort of declarations defined later. But  it's obvious REPL cannot do it. The main reason what you described above happens is as in Martin R's answer, but many other behaviors may be different in REPL and usually compiled environment.

Comment: It remains tricky IMHO, because I am used to REPLs where behaviour does not change, at least in Python I never found something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redeclaring a variable (in the same scope) is not valid in Swift:

```
$ cat test.swift 
let name = "al"
var name = "bob"

$ swiftc test.swift 
test.swift:2:5: error: invalid redeclaration of 'name'
var name = "bob"
    ^
test.swift:1:5: note: 'name' previously declared here
let name = "al"
    ^
```

However, the Swift REPL behaves differently:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.53 clang-802.0.42). Type :help for assistance.
  1> let name = "al" 
name: String = "al"
  2> var name = "bob"
name: String = "bob"
```

This is intentional, as explained in
[Redefining Everything with the Swift REPL](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=20):

> ... but in the REPL interactive environment it’s useful to be able to easily make changes. The REPL was specifically designed with this kind of convenience in mind ...
>
> ... The newer definition replaces the existing definition for all subsequent references

---

*Note:* You have to enter the lines *separately.* If you copy those
two lines into the paste buffer, start the REPL and paste
them with <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> then the result is

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.53 clang-802.0.42). Type :help for assistance.
  1> let name = "al" 
  2. var name = "bob"
error: repl.swift:2:5: error: invalid redeclaration of 'name'
var name = "bob"
    ^
```

Apparently the two statements are now evaluated in the same scope
(the second line has a continuation prompt) and produce an error.
The same happens with both statements in a single line:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.53 clang-802.0.42). Type :help for assistance.
  1> let name = "al" ; var name = "bob"
error: repl.swift:1:23: error: invalid redeclaration of 'name'
let name = "al" ; var name = "bob"
                      ^
```

Comment: Ok, understood, thanks, but it remains a bit... tricky, anyway... especially for noobs...

Comment: Nice catch on the behavior ... It's hard to wrap your head around the concept behind it, especially if you're used to how Python works in interactive mode. It does make perfect sense now about why it was behaving as previsouly observed.

Comment: @l'L'l: Yes, one could argue that the REPL should handle each *statement* differently, this might be a bug.

Comment: Sure I am used to Python REPL and it's the same behaviour as Python IDLE, but, as they say, we always learn something new. Thanks to who explained this strange behaviour.

Comment: @A.N.Other: You are welcome! – But I would suggest that you edit your question a bit and make it clear that the REPL is used.

Comment: let name = "al"; var name = "bob" (on the same line) gives an error, as explained before. Yes, now it's clearer, although I must confess I am still finding it as a bit strange behaviour...

Comment: @A.N.Other: Yes, I was about to add that example. Note also the different prompts (normal vs continuation prompt) if you paste both lines in one. – My guess is that the REPL reads as much as possible from stdin and compiles it. After that, a new "scope" is created.

Comment: @A.N.Other: Does this answer your question now?

Comment: Sure, I forgot to put the flag.

Answer (score 1):

REPL allows re-declaration of a var or let after a var or let, **if entered on a separate line**.

This example is allowed in REPL but not in swiftc:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.0.1 (swiftlang-1001.0.82.4 clang-1001.0.46.4).
Type :help for assistance.
 1> var x = 10
x: Int = 10
 2> let x = 20
x: Int = 20
 3> let x = 30 // allowed in REPL
x: Int = 30
```

You can re-let and re-var in REPL if phrases are entered **line by line**.

But REPL does not allow re-declarations within one line (with semicolons) or, as mentioned in an earlier answer, in pasted blocks:

```
 4> let y = 30; let y=20
error: repl.swift:18:17: error: invalid redeclaration of 'y'
```

Note also that **shebang/hashbang** scripts that call */usr/bin/swift* will use *swiftc* and not the REPL. Perhaps confusingly, both swiftc and swift, as well as the REPL, are all the one and same */usr/bin/swift*

```
#!/usr/bin/swift
let x = 10
let x = 20 // not allowed
```

Redeclaration of **functions** are allowed in the same way:

```
> func x() {} 
> func x() {} // allowed in REPL
> func y() {}; func y() {}  
error: repl.swift:7:19: error: invalid redeclaration of 'y()'
```

As we would expect, function redeclaration applies to the full function signature. Declaring an overload will declare a new function that will live alongside an existing function of the same name but with different arguments. This means that an overload will not necessarily re-declare a previous function of the same name.

Let's declare some **overloading functions**, and let's do so all in one line to demonstrate that they are allowed in REPL.

```
> func y(_:Int) {print("y Int")}; func y(_:String) {print("y String")};
> y(3) 
y Int
> y("Y") 
y String
```

There are two functions, and both have the same name. One takes an Int, the other a String. Let's redeclare the Int one:

```
func y(_:Int) {print("y Int new")};
> y(3)
y Int new
```

And there it is: the output shows it was re-declared.

If you are not used to **captures**, things can get confusing (or dangerous). Watch what happens when a variable in scope gets captured:

```
> var xx=10;
xx: Int = 10
> func x(){print(xx)}; x()
10
```

This is intuitive. But what happens when we **re-declare the captured variable**:

```
> var xx=10; x() 
10
xx: Int = 10
```

Everything still ok? No, wait...

```
> xx=20; x()
10
```

Why 10 and not 20? Inside x() it is still the first var xx=10 that is in scope and captured. This is how captures work. But note that the captured variable no longer exists at the REPL prompt. Redeclaring a captured variable does not get it automatically recaptured.

Sometimes I use REPL to dig into a bug or a language construct, and it is good to know about these subtleties, as they can lead to confusion as to what is happening in your code, or it can lead to misunderstandings of the language.

REPL function overloads and var/let re-declarations are all explained in the blog post mentioned in the earlier answer, see https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=20

I thought I'd summarize some of the findings from the previous answers & comments, and add some more details.