# How do the Swift REPL and the swiftc compiler interpret the language differently?

Tags: swift, read-eval-print-loop

Swift has a compiler (swiftc) and a REPL. I like using the REPL to learn and play with language constructs.

In one of my experiments I came across a notable difference w.r.t how "let" works.

The following is, as I would expect, not allowed in swiftc, but the REPL allows it.

```
let x = 10
let x = 20 // ok in REPL
```

And now I am wondering what other differences there are. Are they documented anywhere?

Comment: Related: [let and var Invalid redeclaration of const in Swift REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45262283).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a REPL environment, you'd *want* to be able to redeclare variables, right? Otherwise, as you keep using the REPL, and you declare more and more variables, `let` constants, functions, classes, whatever, you'll run out of names to use!

For example, let's say you want to try out string interpolation:

```
let x = 10
print("x is \(x)!")
```

And then a while later, you learn about string concatenation, and you want to try that out as well. At this point, you'd want to be able to redeclare a `let` constant `x`, right?

```
let x = "A"
let y = "B"
print(x + y)
```

You could argue that you could use `a` or `b`, but as time goes on, you'll slowly run out of names. REPL is designed like this so that you don't have to restart the REPL very frequently.

So each time you submit something, previously declared symbols that are also declared in the submission will get overwritten. This is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=20).

`swiftc` has a completely different use case - you usually use it to compile larger programs, with more than just a few lines of code. In these situations, the global scope will have a lot less symbols, and redeclaring variables isn't really practical to implement, because the code execution isn't linear from top to bottom. There could be multiple files as well that talk to each other. How do you figure out what redeclares what? It just doesn't make sense to do this in anywhere other than a REPL.

Other REPLs have this feature too, like `csharppad.com` for C#, `ghci` for Haskell, and `python`, just to name a few. So it's really just a common thing you do when you implement REPLs, not something special to Swift.

In fact, you can reproduce the `swiftc` behaviour in a REPL by writing the two lines in a function, because now the two lines are in the same submission, and will not overwrite each other.

Comment: "In a REPL environment, you'd want to be able to redeclare variables, right?" Thank you for your answer, and I understand your point. I would prefer the REPL to behave syntactically the same as the compiler.  For instance, due to this difference, I cannot meaningfully experiment with implicitly unwrapped optionals. Using a form of a deliberate clear/unset to accomplish what you suggest, would make more sense. Any suggestions where this and other REPL/swiftc differences might be listed/documented?

Comment: [This link](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=20) is in the post linked by Martin R. Have a look there. Does that count as "documentation"? @P2000

Comment: @P2000 I don't understand why this feature would prevent you from experimenting with implicitly unwrapped optionals. Can you elaborate?

Comment: OK, you are right. After some deliberation (I am an experienced coder but new to Swift) I'd say it's really a duplicate of the same concern: let can re-let. What I meant is that `let x: Int! = 3` can later become `let x: Int! = int` and expose the nil in subsequent code using x. In microscopic "tinker" code it really does not matter. I was concerned that REPL was used for hash-bang scripts, but it turns out it is not. Your link to Martin R was perfect: "(...) REPL bends normal coding rules". User beware!

Comment: Would you mind adding the link into your answer? I will mark it as answered.